# Get all input values from table excluding first column

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to alert the input value of each row except the first column.
Here is my code.

```
<table id="table">
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" size="5" value="name"/></td>
     <td><input type="text" size="5" value="number"/></td>
     <td><input type="text" size="5" value="class"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td><input type="text" size="5" value="bbbbb"/></td>
     <td><input type="text" size="5" value="1"/></td>
     <td><input type="text" size="5" value="2"/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td><input type="text" size="5" value="cccc"/></td>
     <td><input type="text" size="5" value="5"/></td>
     <td><input type="text" size="5" value="2"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td><input type="text" size="5" value="ddddd"/></td>
     <td><input type="text" size="5" value="1"/></td>
     <td><input type="text" size="5" value="2"/></td>
 </tr>
```

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
$("#table tr:gt(0) td:gt(0) ").each(function()
                {
            a=$(this).find('input[type="text"]').val();
                alert(a);

                });
 });
```

While running this code all value alerted except "bbbb". (ie,ccccc ,dddd alerted.). I only need each rows second one column onwords.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k1tfo5kb/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

https://jsfiddle.net/23jcejbm/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $cells = $("#table tr td").not(':first-child'),
        $inputs = $cells.find('input[type="text"]');

    $.each($inputs, function(){
        var value = this.value;
        alert(value);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/pukw0uLz/1/

I changed `alert` to `console.log`, much less aggressive. Make sure to open you web console!